# How to calculate checksum for example below?

Tags: checksum

Trying to read data from digital IO to serial board and get the result as below

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot 1]

Col B,C,D & E represent the inputs in hex, total 16 inputs.
I believe column F and column G (last to hex) are the checksum but couldn't figure out how to calculate them

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot 2]

The worst part is when the value getting bigger, column F become 7.
Need help/clue on how to calculate the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

G is a simple xor of the four values.
Edit: not quite, only while F =0..